# Glut Lightning doesnt work on GL_TRIANGLES

Tags: c, glut

I have a problem with lightning. Lightning works on:

```
//...
gluSphere(qobj, r1, precision, precision);
//...
```

But it dosnt work on:

```
//...
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
glColor3fv(colors[4]);
glVertex3fv(vertices[triangles[fig2][1]]);
glVertex3fv(vertices[triangles[fig2][2]]);
glVertex3fv(vertices[triangles[fig2][3]]);
glEnd();
//...
```

Here is how it looks:

[img http://img72.imageshack.us/img72/2158/36156234.jpg](http://img72.imageshack.us/img72/2158/36156234.jpg)

As you can see only "gluSphere" is lightened. How to make same lightning on GL_TRIANGLES and GL_POLYGON?

Comment: I think you need to add normals of the faces. OpenGL won't guess them for you.

Comment: Yes! Thanks. Now I just need to close this question somehow...

Comment: I'll post it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lighting engine needs to know which direction a polygon is facing. Instead of calculating those by itself, OpenGL requires you to provide this information through normals:

```
//...
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
glColor3fv(colors[4]);
// put a call to glNormal3fv or glNormal3f here!
glVertex3fv(vertices[triangles[fig2][1]]);
glVertex3fv(vertices[triangles[fig2][2]]);
glVertex3fv(vertices[triangles[fig2][3]]);
glEnd();
//...
```